# How to find $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin 2x}{\sqrt{1+\tan x} - \sqrt{1-\tan x }}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

How to find $\;\;\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin 2x}{\sqrt{1+\tan x} - \sqrt{1-\tan x }}$ ?

Comment: Hint: Rationalise the denominator and use limx->0 sinx/x=1 and tanx/x=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Multiply the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{1 + \tan x} + \sqrt {1-\tan x}$.

Your denominator will become $1 + \tan x - (1-\tan x) = 2\tan x$.

Comment: This is a good answer: good hints, no spoon-feeding. +1

Comment: @Timbuc Well, someone out there has been taking delight in downvoting my answers lately. Thank you for your vote of confidence.

Comment: I haven't seen him in a while, but I'm sure my teacher donantonio sends you his best regards. He also used to tell me, when he introduced me to this site and taught me how to write and etc., that sometimes there are trolling downvoters. It hasn't happened to me so far, but I guess it'll happen sometime in the future. Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$f(x) = \dfrac{\sin(2x)}{\sqrt{1+\tan(x)} - \sqrt{1-\tan(x)}} = \dfrac{\sin(2x)}{\sqrt{1+\tan(x)} - \sqrt{1-\tan(x)}} \dfrac{\sqrt{1+\tan(x)} + \sqrt{1-\tan(x)}}{\sqrt{1+\tan(x)} + \sqrt{1-\tan(x)}}$$
Hence,
$$f(x) = \dfrac{\sin(2x) \left(\sqrt{1+\tan(x)} + \sqrt{1-\tan(x)}\right)}{1+\tan(x) - 1 + \tan(x)} = \dfrac{2\sin(x)\cos(x) \left(\sqrt{1+\tan(x)} + \sqrt{1-\tan(x)}\right)}{2\tan(x)}$$
This gives us
$$f(x) = \cos^2(x) \left(\sqrt{1+\tan(x)} + \sqrt{1-\tan(x)}\right)$$
Now take the limit as $x \to 0$ to get $f(x) \to 2$.

Comment: Avoid spoon feeding

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Don't worry, I used the hint :D

Comment: @omidh, Its not only about you. Also, here in MSE, the common practice for answering is to leave some room for thought for the OP

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I'm agree with you

Answer (score 1):

Sinc you received already good answers, let me show you what you can do using Taylor series. You know that, for small values of $x$, $\tan(x)\approx x$ and that $\sin(x)\approx x$. So the expression is almost $$\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}$$ Now remember that $\sqrt{1+y}\approx \frac y2$. So the expression is $$\frac{2x}{(\frac x2)-(-\frac x2)}$$

Comment: Good for guessing the answer but to make it rigorous you need to include the error terms and throw them away only when not needed.

Comment: Very useful way, Thanks!

Comment: @user21820. I totally agree with you but I did not want to invade the space with that. I limited to the strict minimum. May I confess that I m in love with Taylor series ... for more than 55 years ?

Comment: @omidh. The beauty of Taylor series is that not only you get the limit but you also see how the limit is approached. In the case of your problem, the expression behaves just as $2-\frac{9 x^2}{4}+O\left(x^4\right)$. Plot the two curves on the same graph for $-1/2<x<1/2$; you should be amazed.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Did you ever see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/809591/21820? You should be able to get the answer without looking at my solution. Some computer algebra systems cannot.

Comment: @user21820. This is incredibly beautiful ! For sure, for this kind of problems, CAS are just dumb ! Thank you. Cheers :-)